# gcc 10+ stopped creating the conversion warning

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I've stumbled upon this little warning in my code.

```
#include "stdint.h"

uint16_t a = 25;
uint16_t data = (uint16_t)4095u - a;
```

With `-Wconversion` flag set, `gcc` 9.2 produces this warning:

```
<source>:4:33: warning: conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} may change value [-Wconversion]
    4 | uint16_t data = (uint16_t)4095u - a;
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

But the later `gcc` versions compile this code fine. Example is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hsY6Ma577).
Can anyone provide the explanation? Is the newer compiler just smart enough to perform the casting explicitly?

Thank you.

Comment: It has always "performed the casting explicitly".  What has changed here, I suspect, is that the optimizer can tell there is no danger here, because it knows the value of `a`.  If `a` were a function parameter, I'm guessing you'd see the warning again.

Comment: Optimizer is off.

Comment: Irrelevant.  The compiler is 100% confident of the value of `a` and therefore knows that there will be no loss of data.

Comment: So your hypothesis, @TimRoberts is that the later compiler just can figure this out better?

Comment: Right.  In this case, it KNEW that information all along, but it's now USING that information to decide whether to issue the warning or not.